# how can I include a text file in a project and reference its contents from the project's code?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working with .NET 8, porting a project written with .NET Framework 4.7.

In .NET Framework, I could add a file to the project with "Build Action": "Resource", and then I could access its contents as a string by doing something like this:

```
string fileContent = Properties.Resources.file_name;
```

This doesn't seem to work in .NET 8.

Is there a way to do this, without actually including the file in the build output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still use resource file like this in .NET8. Try following:

Create a file `test.txt` with content "txt file content".

Right click the project name, open project-properties board.
[image]

Then choose Add Existing File to choose `test.txt`
[image]

Then you could get the file string.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to embed resource first.

It will look something like this but you can do same from properties for that file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="path to text file" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For example this file resource name is like text.txt.

You can read like this.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

Comment: is this "better" than doing it the way I described in the OP? this way certainly adds much less noise to source control. Are there any significant performance or security differences or anything?